# Не могу выставить приложение в app store

Tags: ios, xcode

Не могу создать Identifiers -> iOS App IDs, ввожу свой Bundle id  постоянно выбивает  There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit. An App ID with Identifier '**(мой Bundle id)**' is not available. Please enter a different string.   и ничего, в чем может быть причина? работаю с x-code 9
apple id разработчика регистрировали на юр лицо

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой.
Решение - меняйте **Bundle id**. Если такая ошибка возникает то такой **Bundle id** который вы используете, использовать не получиться.